# How to solve this Integral operator equation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to solve this exercise.

Let $ L:C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1]) $ such that $$ (Lu)(t) = \int_{0}^{t^2} u(\sqrt{s}) ds. $$ Let $ a\in R $ and consider the following:
$$ Lu = au. $$ Show that necessarily $ u\equiv 0. $

Some ideas to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have with the substitution $s=x^2$, formally $ds=2x\; dx$:
$$
(Lu)(t) = 
\int_0^{t^2}u(\sqrt s)\; ds
=
\int_0^{t}u(x)\;2x\; dx\ ,
$$
so in particular $(Lu)(0)=0$. Assume now $u$ is a solution for 
$Lu = au$.

- If $a=0$, then we immediately deduce $u(x)\; 2x\equiv 0$, so $u=0$.
- Else, $u=\frac 1aLu$ is  differentiable, and we compute
  $$
  u'(t) = \frac 1a(Lu)'(t)
  =
  \frac 1a u(t)\, 2t\ .
  $$
  This is a differential equation in $u$, we have also $u(0)=0$, the solution is unique, namely $u=0$. For this we may want to solve the equation or compute the differential of $u(t)\cdot\exp-\frac {t^2}a$. Let us do this explicitly.

---

It is convenient to use $$c=\frac 2a$$ below, so we can concentrate on the essential part.

- Solving the equation. We have to solve $u'(t) = ct\; u(t)$. We solve locally around points where $u\ne 0$, so that we can rephrase successively equivalently:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  u'(t) &= ct\; u(t)\\
  \frac{u'(t)}{u(t)} &= ct\qquad\text{Now integrate on both sides:}\\
  \log |u(t)| &=ct^2/2 +\text{Constant}\\
  u(t) &= \pm Ke^{ct^2/2}\ ,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  and we can stop here. If $u\ne 0$ on some point of $[0,1]$, then locally we have the above form. Since $u$ is continuous, the above form either has $K=0$, and then $u=0$, or $K\ne 0$, but then the above form has no chance to become $u(0)=0$.
- The last argument may seem unclear, but with its knowledge we can argument as follows. Let $h(t) = u(t)\; e^{-ct^2/2}$. (And we want to show it is constant. So it is constant zero.) Then the derivative of $h$ is
  $$
  h'(t) = 
  u'(t)\; e^{-ct^2/2} + u(t)\; (e^{-ct^2/2})'
  =
  u(t)\; ct \; e^{-ct^2/2} +
  u(t)\; (-ct \; e^{-ct^2/2}) = 0\ .
  $$
  So $h$ is a constant, and from $h(0)$ we get $h=0$, then $u=0$.

Comment: i've added some more details, please always do not hesitate to ask, if some part is unclear.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thank you!